# Auto Numbering in a single cell

Tags: worksheet-function, formatting

I want a Cell to Auto-populate a Tracking # in a form that several people have access to on a shared drive.  Example:

I open the Exception Form for the first time and it should show SL(date)-#:
result SL11-05-001. I close the autosaved form, then my co-worker opens the Form and it automatically shows SL11-05-002. The Form is opened the next day and it would Auto # the Tracking # as SL11-06-01.

So basically is Text(TODAY)and then a number that is autogenerating each time it's opened by anyone who has access to the form on a shared drive.